# Find a general solution of the linear differential equation for all values of the parameter $a$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is:

$ y'' - 2y' + ay = 0$.

This is my attempt:

It is 2nd Order with constant coefficients:

$ r^2 - 2r + a = 0$ $(*)$

$ \implies (r - \sqrt{a})(r - \sqrt{a}) = 0$

Then, $ r = \sqrt{a} $ is a solution if $a = 1$.

But what if $a \neq 1$? Then $r = \sqrt{a}$ is no longer a solution to $(*)$. How can I find the general for all values of $a$?

Comment: Thats not the right factorisation you should get: $(r-(1-\sqrt{(1-a)}))(r-(1+\sqrt{(1-a)}))$

Comment: can you explain how you got that?

Comment: Find the roots of the quadratic and then write the  polynomial in terms of its roots:  $(r-x_0)(r-x_1)$ the roots are $x_0$ and $x_1$

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking for an explanation of how the roots were found.

Comment: Thats basic just search on Math SE for the solutions of a quadratic and you'll find the answer